# Search over fields from related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is table `topics`:

- int `id`
- string `label`

This is table `articles`:

- int `id`
- string `label`
- string `content`
- int `topic_id` (foreign key)

This is table `comments`:

- int `id`
- string `content`
- string `article_id` (foreign key)

Now, I want to implement a search function that yields all articles where the search term (LIKE %term%) is included either in

- the article’s `label` or `content`
- the `label` of the article’s topic
- `content` of comments that belong to this article

I think the solution may have something to do with JOINS, but I absolutely have no idea how to do this. Can anybody help?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered and ruled out using FULLTEXT searching? It may meet your needs pretty well.

Comment: @O.Jones His question is about how to combine the tables, not how to match the fields themselves.

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with JOINs. If you don't know how to do JOINs, you need to read a good SQL tutorial, this isn't a programming school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are a newbie and don't want to implement a "Full Text Search" solution. Therefore, a simple SQL would be:

```
select a.*
  from topics t
  join articles a on a.topic_id = t.id
  join comments c on c.article_id = a.id
  where a.label like '%term%'
     or a.content like '%term%'
     or t.label like '%term%'
     or c.content like '%term%'
```

Please note, the performance of this SQL solution is not great when dealing with a high volume or topics, articles or comments. However, it will work well and will return the articles you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!